# stack geotiff with stars 'along' when 'band' dimension contains band + time information

Tags: r, geospatial, terra, r-stars

I have a timeseries of geotiff files I'd like to stack in R using stars.  Here's the first two:

```r
urls <- paste0("/vsicurl/",
"https://sdsc.osn.xsede.org/bio230014-bucket01/neon4cast-drivers/",
"noaa/gefs-v12/cogs/gefs.20221201/",
c("gep01.t00z.pgrb2a.0p50.f003.tif", "gep01.t00z.pgrb2a.0p50.f006.tif"))

library(stars)
stars::read_stars(urls, along="time")
```

Errors with:

```
Error in c.stars_proxy(`3` = list(gep01.t00z.pgrb2a.0p50.f003.tif = "/vsicurl/https://sdsc.osn.xsede.org/bio230014-bucket01/neon4cast-drivers/noaa/gefs-v12/cogs/gefs.20221201/gep01.t00z.pgrb2a.0p50.f003.tif"),  : 
  don't know how to merge arrays: please specify parameter along
```

### Context: bands contain both time+band info

This fails because the dimensions do not match, which happens because the files have concatenated temporal information into the band names:

```r
x<- lapply(urls, read_stars)
x
```

produces:

```
[[1]]
stars object with 3 dimensions and 1 attribute
attribute(s), summary of first 1e+05 cells:
                                       Min.  1st Qu. Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max.
gep01.t00z.pgrb2a.0p50.f003.ti...  50026.01 98094.81 101138 98347.42 101845.2 104605.2
dimension(s):
     from  to  offset delta                       refsys point
x       1 720 -180.25   0.5 Coordinate System importe... FALSE
y       1 361   90.25  -0.5 Coordinate System importe... FALSE
band    1   8      NA    NA                           NA    NA
                                                           values x/y
x                                                            NULL [x]
y                                                            NULL [y]
band PRES:surface:3 hour fcst,...,DLWRF:surface:0-3 hour ave fcst    

[[2]]
stars object with 3 dimensions and 1 attribute
attribute(s), summary of first 1e+05 cells:
                                       Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean 3rd Qu.     Max.
gep01.t00z.pgrb2a.0p50.f006.ti...  50029.83 98101.83 101170.6 98337.52  101825 104588.2
dimension(s):
     from  to  offset delta                       refsys point
x       1 720 -180.25   0.5 Coordinate System importe... FALSE
y       1 361   90.25  -0.5 Coordinate System importe... FALSE
band    1   8      NA    NA                           NA    NA
                                                           values x/y
x                                                            NULL [x]
y                                                            NULL [y]
band PRES:surface:6 hour fcst,...,DLWRF:surface:0-6 hour ave fcst
```

Note the band names would align except for the existence of the timestamp being tacked on, e.g. `PRES:surface:3 hour fcst` vs `PRES:surface:6 hour fcst`.

How can I best read in these files so that I have dimensions of x,y,band, and time in my stars object?

### alternatives: terra?

How about `terra`?  Note that `terra` is happy to read these files in directly, but treats this as 16 unique bands.  Can I re-align that so that I have the original 8 bands along a new "time" dimension?  (I recognize stars emphasizes 'spatio-temporal', maybe the such a cube is out of scope to terra?)  Also note that terra for some reason mangles the timestamp in these band names:

```r
x <- terra::rast(urls)
x
```

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 361, 720, 16  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent      : -180.25, 179.75, -90.25, 90.25  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat Coordinate System imported from GRIB file 
sources     : gep01.t00z.pgrb2a.0p50.f003.tif  (8 layers) 
              gep01.t00z.pgrb2a.0p50.f006.tif  (8 layers) 
names       : PRES:~ fcst, TMP:2~ fcst, RH:2 ~ fcst, UGRD:~ fcst, VGRD:~ fcst, APCP:~ fcst, .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With terra it is pretty easy to make a time-series for each variable as I show below.

```
urls <- paste0("/vsicurl/",
"https://sdsc.osn.xsede.org/bio230014-bucket01/neon4cast-drivers/",
"noaa/gefs-v12/cogs/gefs.20221201/",
c("gep01.t00z.pgrb2a.0p50.f003.tif", "gep01.t00z.pgrb2a.0p50.f006.tif"))

library(terra)
r <- rast(urls)
```

Extract two variables of interest

```
nms <- names(r)
tmp <- r[[grep("TMP", nms)]]
rh <- r[[grep("RH", nms)]]

# set time
tm <- as.POSIXct("2022-12-01", tz="GMT") + c(3,6) * 3600
time(rh) <- tm 
time(tmp) <- tm
```

And you could combine them into a SpatRasterDatset like this:

```
s <- sds(list(tmp=tmp, rh=rh))
```

An alternative path to get to the same point would be to start with a SpatRasterDataset and subset it.

```
sd <- sds(urls)
nl <- 1:length(sd)
nms <- names(sd[1])

tmp2 <- rast(sd[nl, grep("TMP", nms)])
time(tmp2) <- tm

rh2 <- rast(sd[nl, grep("RH", nms)])
time(rh2) <- tm
```

---

I made the subsetting work a little nicer in terra version 1.7-5

```
urls <- paste0("/vsicurl/",
"https://sdsc.osn.xsede.org/bio230014-bucket01/neon4cast-drivers/",
"noaa/gefs-v12/cogs/gefs.20221201/", c("gep01.t00z.pgrb2a.0p50.f003.tif", "gep01.t00z.pgrb2a.0p50.f006.tif"))

library(terra)
#terra 1.7.5
sd <- sds(urls)
tmp <- sd[,2]

tmp
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 361, 720, 2  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
#extent      : -180.25, 179.75, -90.25, 90.25  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat Coordinate System imported from GRIB file 
#sources     : gep01.t00z.pgrb2a.0p50.f003.tif  
#              gep01.t00z.pgrb2a.0p50.f006.tif  
#names       : TMP:2 m above g~Temperature [C], TMP:2 m above g~Temperature [C] 
#unit        :                               C,                               C 
#time        : 2022-12-01 03:00:00 to 2022-12-01 06:00:00 UTC
```

As for the layer names containing the forecast time, that is just because that is what is in the tif metadata. It looks like that was a decision made when they were created from the original GRIB files.

The latitude extent going beyond the north and south poles is an interesting feature of this dataset.

Comment: oh wow! the sds approach there is really nice, especially in the dev version you show there.  

Yup, funny coordinates come from the grib files; I've merely gdal_translate'd to COG, but actually I think we can use gribs directly, e.g.:

gribs <- c("/vsicurl/https://noaa-gefs-pds.s3.amazonaws.com/gefs.20220314/00/atmos/pgrb2ap5/gec00.t00z.pgrb2a.0p50.f003",
           "/vsicurl/https://noaa-gefs-pds.s3.amazonaws.com/gefs.20220314/00/atmos/pgrb2ap5/gec00.t00z.pgrb2a.0p50.f006")
cube <- terra::sds(gribs)

will have to explore...

Comment: works beautifully with the full grib collection too!  added a quick example, really like your new subset format for the sds group.  :-) thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to share some additional possible solutions for comparison.  With larger numbers of files some of these differences become more relevant. this expands a bit beyond my original question.

## terra

Prof Hijmans gives a very nice solution in terra. He also asked about the original upstream sources, which I didn't explain properly -- these are originally GRIB files for [NOAA GEFS forecast](https://www.nco.ncep.noaa.gov/pmb/products/gens).

Notably, we can work directly from the GRIB files. GEFS is a 35-day forecast, so let's try going more than 6 hrs into the future:

```r
library(terra)

# original GRIB sources, AWS mirror
gribs <- paste0("/vsicurl/https://noaa-gefs-pds.s3.amazonaws.com/gefs.20220314/00/atmos/pgrb2ap5/geavg.t00z.pgrb2a.0p50.f",
                stringr::str_pad(seq(3,240,by=3), 3, pad="0"))

bench::bench_time({
  cube <- terra::sds(gribs)
})

cube[1,63] |> plot()
```

[image: world forecast tmp]

very nice!

### gdalcubes

[gdalcubes](https://cran.r-project.org/package=gdalcubes) is another package that can also leverage the gdal virtual filesystem when working with these large-ish remote files.  It also lets us define an abstract cube at potentially a different resolution in space & time than the original sources (averaging or interpolating). lazy operations mean this may run a bit faster(?)

```r
library(gdalcubes)
date <- as.Date("2023-01-26")
date_time = date + lubridate::hours(seq(3,240,by=3))

# USA box
v <- cube_view(srs = "EPSG:4326", 
               extent = list(left = -125, right = -66,top = 49, bottom = 25,
                             t0= as.character(min(date_time)), t1=as.character(max(date_time))),
               dx = 0.5, dy = 0.5, dt = "PT3H")

gribs <- paste0("/vsicurl/https://noaa-gefs-pds.s3.amazonaws.com/gefs.20220314/00/atmos/pgrb2ap5/geavg.t00z.pgrb2a.0p50.f",
                stringr::str_pad(seq(3,240,by=3), 3, pad="0"))

bench::bench_time({
  cube <- gdalcubes::create_image_collection(gribs, date_time = date_time)
})

bench::bench_time({
  raster_cube(cube, v) |>
    select_bands("band63") |> # tempearture
    animate(col = viridisLite::viridis, nbreaks=50, fps=10, save_as = "temp.gif")
})
```

[image: gif animation of forecast tmp]

## stars

didn't translate a full stars example, but here at least is the band name correction; a bit more cumbersome than the examples above.

```r
urls <- paste0("/vsicurl/",
"https://sdsc.osn.xsede.org/bio230014-bucket01/neon4cast-drivers/",
"noaa/gefs-v12/cogs/gefs.20221201/",
c("gep01.t00z.pgrb2a.0p50.f003.tif", "gep01.t00z.pgrb2a.0p50.f006.tif"))

library(stars)
#stars::read_stars(urls, along="time") # no luck!


## grab unstacked proxy object for each geotiff
x <- lapply(urls, read_stars)

# extract band-names-part
band_names <- st_get_dimension_values(x[[1]], "band") |> 
  stringr::str_extract("([A-Z]+):") |>
  str_remove(":")
# apply corrected band-names
x1 <- lapply(x, st_set_dimensions, "band", band_names)

# at last, we can stack into a cube:
x1 <- do.call(c, c(x1, along="time"))

# and add correct date timestamps to the new time dimension
dates <- as.Date("2022-12-01") + lubridate::hours(c(3,6))
x1 <- st_set_dimensions(x1, "time", dates)
x1
```